# Debugging a remote process

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, remote-debugging

I have a general question about debugging a .NET process that has been built locally but deployed to a remote machine.

If the process was built in DEBUG mode and was deployed WITH pdb's, is there any software or technologies available that allow you to hook in or attach to the process for debugging purposes without installing visual studio? Which would allow you to step through executing code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [How To Set Up Remote Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) for starters

Answer (score 3):

Please keep in mind that remote debugging of managed code require two-way communication through RPC between debugger and debuggee. 
You need to grant mutual rights on both machines, open proper ports and make sure any firewall between will not block communication to either side